# Convert the value of a field in a django RawQueryset to a different django field type

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset, django-postgresql

I have a rather complex query that's generating a Django `RawQuerySet`. This specific query returns some fields that aren't part of the model that the `RawQuerySet` is based on, so I'm using `.annotate(field_name=models.Value('field_name'))` to attach it as an attribute to individual records in the `RawQuerySet`. The most important custom field is actually a `uuid`, which I use to compose URLs using Django's `{% url %}` functionality.

Here's the problem: I'm not using standard `uuid`s inside my app, I'm using [SmallUUIDs](https://github.com/adamcharnock/django-smalluuid) (compressed UUIDs.) These are stored in the database as native `uuidfield`s then converted to shorter strings in python. So I need to somehow convert the `uuid` returned as part of the `RawQuerySet` to a `SmallUUID` for use inside a template to generate a URL.

My code looks somewhat like this:

```
query = "SELECT othertable.uuid_field as my_uuid FROM myapp_mymodel
         JOIN othertable o ON myapp_mymodel.x = othertable.x"

MyModel.objects.annotate(
    my_uuid=models.Value('my_uuid'),
).raw(query)
```

Now there is a logical solution here, there's an optional kwarg for `models.Value` called `output_field`, making the code look like this:

```
MyModel.objects.annotate(
    my_uuid=models.Value('my_uuid', output_field=SmallUUIDField()),
).raw(query)
```

But it doesn't work! That kwarg is completely ignored and the type of the attribute is based on the type returned from the database and not what's in `output_field`. In my case, I'm getting a `uuid` output because Postgres is returning a UUID type, but if I were to change the query to `SELECT cast othertable.uuid_field as text) as my_uuid` I'd get the attribute in the format of a string. It appears that Django (at least version 1.11.12) doesn't actually care what is in that kwarg in this instance.

So here's what I'm thinking are my potential solutions, in no particular order:

1. Change the way the query is formatted somehow (either in Django or in the SQL)
2. Change the resulting RawQuerySet in some way before it's passed to the view
3. Change something inside the templates to convert the UUID to a smalluuid for use in the URL reverse process.

What's my best next steps here?

Comment: Since `SmallUUIDField` is not a native Django model field type, are you sure it's compatible with what you're trying to do?  If you want text output, why not just use `TextField`?

Comment: It actually appears that even native model field types are ignored with `output_field` in this circumstance. You can set `output_field` to an `IntField` and if it's a string from the database it'll still show up as a string. In fact, it doesn't even appear as a standard django "field", it just shows up as a string (or in my case uuid.) It really does just return what the database returns. And I need the shortened version of the UUID, which is a custom feature of that field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of issues with your current approach:

1. `Value()` isn't doing what you think it is - your annotation is literally just annotating each row with the value "my_uuid" because that is what you have passed to it. It isn't looking up the field of that name (to do that you need to use `F` expressions).
2. Point 1 above doesn't matter anyway because as soon as you use `raw()` then the annotation is ignored - which is why you see no effect coming from it.

Bottom line is that trying to annotate a `RawQuerySet` isn't going to be easy. There is a `translations` argument that it accepts, but I can't think of a way to get that to work with the type of join you are using.

The next best suggestion that I can think of is that you just manually convert the field into a `SmallUUID` object when you need it - something like this:

```
from smalluuid import SmallUUID

objects = MyModel.objects.raw(query)

for o in objects:
    # Take the hex string obtained from the database and convert it to a SmallUUID object.
    # If your database has a built-in UUID type you will need to do 
    # SmallUUID(small=o.my_uuid) instead.
    my_uuid = SmallUUID(hex=o.my_uuid)
```

(I'm doing this in a loop just to illustrate - depending on where you need this you can do it in a template tag or view).

Comment: Thanks! The fact that annotation is ignored with raw queries isn't especially well documented (in fact, a lot to do with RawQuerySet isn't especially well documented.)